# Network is unreachable

Tags: networking, routing, router, netplan, virtualbox-networking

I have one server using `192.168.1.2/24` and the other server using `192.168.2.2/24`. They are connected on my router with separate adapters.

I tried ping test from my router, it worked.

However, when I tried to ping from `192.168.1.2` to `192.168.2.2`, the command said: `connect: Network is unreachable`.

What should I do?

Comment: Can you [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1084865/edit) your question and post the output of `traceroute 192.168.2.2` from `192.168.1.2` , `ip address` and `ip route` of both servers?

Comment: Can both of the servers ping the router?

Comment: Yes I can ping both of router

Answer (score 0):

Servers are in different subnets:

- Server 1: 192.168.1.2/24 belongs to subnet 192.168.1.0
- Server 2: 192.168.2.2/24 belongs to subnet 192.168.2.0

You have to set your router to allow both subnets can reach each other. Also, I suppose you have to set the routes in your serves because the message `connect: Network is unreachable` suggest me that there is no route configured.