# I can only ping google and ubuntu

Tags: networking, server, internet, connection, ping

I am using ubuntu-server 19.10 and I can only ping (from what I have tried) google.com, youtube.com and ubuntu.com.

I however cannot `ping`, `wget` or `git clone` from github.com, cnet.com, duckduckgo.com, sourceforge.net, 8.8.8.8, 172.217.17.142 ...

Whenever I try to ping them I get the message:

```
ping: connect: Network is unreachable
```

How can I connect to these websites?

EDIT: `ping -n xyz` gets the same result.

```
traceroute -n duckduckgo.com:
traceroute to duckduckgo.com (79.125.108.59) hops max, 60 byte packets
```

Comment: A bit more info is needed to answer. 

At least:

ping -n duckduckgo.com

ping -n ubuntu.com

and 

traceroute -n duckduckgo.com

traceroute -n ubuntu.com

Preferable some more info about your config, as in https://askubuntu.com/questions/1084865/network-is-unreachable

Comment: that was the entire output of the failed ping.

Comment: I ended up assigning a new ipv4 address to my server

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It looks like these having A and AAAA-Records registered properly:

- google.com
- youtube.com
- ubuntu.com

It looks like those dont have / misconfigured AAAA-Records but have A-Records:

- github.com
- cnet.com
- duckduckgo.com

Tested with [this DNS Record Viewer](http://dns-record-viewer.online-domain-tools.com/)

Does your server get a public IPv4?

To me it looks like your server can't access servers that only have an DNS A-Record cause it doesn't have an IPv4-adress itself.
If that is the case you can:

- try / ask for assigning an IPv4 to your server
- tuneling IPv6 to IPv4 by a proxy software i.e. 6tunnel or similar
- wait / ask for those website IPv6 support

Comment: I somehow didn't have an ipv4 address. Thanks.

Comment: I had this once in my home network. It was interresting to observe which part of the internet works with IPv6 only, and which part doesn't.

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann you might already know: There are internet providers applying DS-Lite to (private) customers. This means you will get a personal IPv6 but share IPv4 with other customer. 
As long as you access internet from your personal router you are all good unless you want to setup a server within a DMZ etc. on your side that can be accessed from internet. This will only work if the person accessing server has IPv6 - if the person will possibly only have IPv4 you should set up a tunnel / proxy on an IPv4&IPv6-ready internet server that routes from IPv4 to IPv6 going to your router this way.