# Can't install software with curl commands

Tags: software-installation, 22.04, curl

I tried to install code-server and pi-hole, but ran into problems. When I install code-server with the command from this [website](https://coder.com/docs/code-server/latest/install#installsh), without the silent:

```
curl -fSL https://code-server.dev/install.sh | sh
```

I get this output:

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
100 15572  100 15572    0     0  13680      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:--  310k
curl: (28) Failed to connect to github.com port 443 after 130742 ms: Connection timed out
```

When I try to install pi-hole with the command from this [website](https://github.com/pi-hole/pi-hole/#one-step-automated-install),

```
curl -SL https://install.pi-hole.net | bash
```

I get:

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:02:09 --:--:--     0
curl: (28) Failed to connect to install.pi-hole.net port 443 after 129292 ms: Connection timed out
```

It seems like this problem is due to some settings on my machine, so I did a complete reinstall of Ubuntu. Now it is just Ubuntu 22.04 running with vnc-server installed. However, that didn't change anything.

Edit:

I disabled the firewall, and nothing changed. I'm not behind a proxy. Here is the output from iptable:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Comment: Something is blocking the connections and it's not really possible to tell without details about your network setup and configuration. Good first places to check would be the firewall (if any) and iptables to see if the packages are being dropped by your machine. If not, are you behind a proxy?

Comment: Turns out I couldn't ping anything besides google. Like this [problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1217542/i-can-only-ping-google-and-ubuntu). The solution was to assign a new IP address.